# Kibana integrated with Firehose

Tags: kibana, kibana-5

I am pushing two different tools data in Elastic search using Kinesis Firehose. I need to display data in Kibana and I am able to do it separately But i want these two indexes to display in single index that means want to merge index and display.

Both the indexes names are different from each other. Example:

1st index- animal
2nd index- Human
To display in single index, Species.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an alias in ElasticSearch for your indices, something like
POST to

```
your.elasticsearch.domain/_aliases
```

Body:

```
{
    "actions" : [
        { "add" : { "indices" : ["Animal", "Human"], "alias" : "Species" } },
    ]
}
```

Then you should be able to use Species as a index pattern in Kibana.